# Create a prediction game on Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to improve my basic "answering" program that returns a random answer on Javascript?

Something like:

```
var question = prompt("Ask something: ");
var randomizer = Math.random();
var answer;

if (randomizer > 0.1 && randomizer < 0.5) {
answer = alert ("Yes, it will.");
} else {
answer = alert ("That won't happen.");
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific in what you want? How many random answers do you want? Are all the answers random?

Comment: There probably is, but just asking for general value judgements of working code is not even slightly in SO's mission.

Comment: Any program that does not work correctly can be improved. In your case you are comparing a **function** (`Math.random`) to a **number** (`0.1`) which is definitely incorrect. Additionally you are not using `question` anywhere and since `alert` does not return anything, the assignment to `answer` is unnecessary.

Comment: @depperm 
By now I just need two answers, and yes, I need random answers.

Comment: @PabloIvan, SO isn't really the place for these code review questions.. however, there IS a code review StackOverflow/StackExchange community http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ in which these questions are appropriate

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now I know that, I didn't back when I asked this question last year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add some brackets.

```js
var question = prompt("Ask something: ", '');
var randomizer = Math.random;
if (randomizer() < 0.5) { // call function randomizer with ()
    alert(question + " Yes, it will.");
} else {
    alert(question + " That won't happen.");
}
```